# Ajax FormData using POST type but in PHP file no request can be fetched

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am unable to figure out the problem .I apology in advance if I have lack of knowledge and did silly mistakes. Here is my piece of code.

```
    <!-- Piece of html -->
    <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Service image" id="edit_service_image-1" type="file" name="file_image">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="processIt(<?php echo $service['service_id'];?>,'esi',document.getElementById('edit_service_image-1').files[0])">Edit</button>
```

The javascript function :->

```
    function processIt(id,flag,inputvalue)
    {

         var filedata = new FormData();
         filedata.append('imagefile', inputvalue);
         filedata.append('id', id);
         filedata.append('flag', flag);
         $.ajax({
                    url: 'modify.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    inputvalue: filedata,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    cache: false
                }).success(function(msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                });


    }
```

Here is modify.php (Only test code)

```
    <?php
      if(isset($_REQUEST['flag']) && !empty($_REQUEST['flag']) && isset($_REQUEST['id']) && !empty($_REQUEST['id']) )
        {
         $flag = $_REQUEST['flag'];
         $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
         echo "Processed";
        }
       else
        echo "Request not processed";
    ?>
```

So my problem is its always alerting "Request Not Processed", which means nothing is getting posted using ajax POST . I am confused, couldn't figure out the exact problem.

**Edit**

Another test code of modify.php

```
     <?php
        print_r($_FILES);
        print_r($_POST);
     ?>
```

In this case the output is -->

```
    Array{

    }
    Array{

    }
```

**SOLVED**

Thanks to everybody who guided me
Just a change in javascript worked . Here's the following changed code in processIt() function, which served my purpose->

```
 function processIt(id,flag,inputvalue)
    {

         var filedata = new FormData();
         filedata.append('imagefile', inputvalue);
         filedata.append('id', id);
         filedata.append('flag', flag);
         $.ajax({
                    url: 'modify.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: filedata, // Here instead of inputvalue it's changed to data
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    cache: false
                }).success(function(msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                });


    }
```

Comment: did you try to change `$_REQUEST` to `$_POST`?

Comment: Yes I tried, but it was same

Comment: can you do a `print_r($_POST);` on the beginning of the PHP script and edit the output in your question?

Comment: Yes I did it already . It was showing output
        Array {

        }

Comment: Use the Network tab of your browser's developer tools. Do you see the data you expect in the request?

Comment: @Mikey I tried ,  but its still same.

Comment: In Network tab I can't find anything. I mean I found the tab but how to check the expected request - I don't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am basing my answer off this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8244082/1022914). Not sure where you got `inputvalue` from, but replace it with `data`.

```
function processIt(id, flag, inputvalue)
{
     var data = new FormData();
     data.append('imagefile', inputvalue);
     data.append('id', id);
     data.append('flag', flag);

     $.ajax({
        url: 'modify.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
     });
}
```

And just a friendly code review in your PHP code, avoid using `$_REQUEST` and you are doing too much unnecessary checking in your IF condition. Here's one way to fix it:

```
if (!empty($_POST['flag']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) {
    $flag = $_POST['flag'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    echo "Processed";
} else {
    echo "Request not processed";
}
```

You may also try [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function which offers some validation and sanitization features. Unfortunately, there is no INPUT_FILE and you have to use `$_FILES` array.

Assuming id is an integer, you could do something like:

```
$flag = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'flag', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if ($flag && $id) {
   echo "Processed";
} else {
   echo "Request not processed";
}
```

Comment: Hi, Mikey. Thanks now its worked. I just used data: filedata, in my code. I need not to change the name of filedata and now its WORKED. :)

Comment: Awesome. I edited my answer with some extra information regarding your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your "inputvalue" with "data".

So your code will look more like this:

```
function processIt(id,flag,inputvalue)
{

     var filedata = new FormData();
     filedata.append('imagefile', inputvalue);
     filedata.append('id', id);
     filedata.append('flag', flag);
     $.ajax({
                url: 'modify.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { mydata: filedata },
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                cache: false
            }).success(function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
            });
}
```

And then in your modify.php do:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

To see if the post data is accessable.

Comment: I tried adding var_dump($_POST) and its showing output -> array(0){ }

Comment: if you do console.log(filedata) what is the output?

Comment: its showing `FormData {}` in console and if I click on it its showing so may things , I don't understand. But as much as I can see no intended value shown

Comment: Can you comment your lines where you populate filedata and do something like : var filedata = "test"; and see if this get passed to php ?

Comment: That's cool. Don't see why I get -1 but well, haters are everywhere

Comment: Seems so, yours was the correct answer . From yours and Mikey's answer I am able to solve my exact issue, though it was actually a small issue, but big help.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea how did you get this option: `inputvalue:` but this will do:

```
function processIt(id,flag,inputvalue){

    $.ajax({
                    url: 'modify.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {inputvalue:'imagefile',id:id, flag:flag},
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(msg) {
                       alert(msg);

                      }

                });


    }
```

Comment: That won't work. You can't include files by passing a plain object to `data`.

Comment: I mean don't we need FormData() ?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see you were uploading a file. in old browsers you can't use direct ajax. is that ok to use ajaxForm plugin ? it's very easy and no need lot of codes